# Local variable in function is not initialized and remembers previous function calls

Tags: python, object, methods, local-variables

I'm new at Python programming and have little to no experience in object oriented programming in general. I came across a problem which I cannot really understand. I know where the problem is, but I don't know why it is there. Since I want to understand the basics of object oriented programming, switching to existing libraries is not an option for me.

So here is what I want to do:
I have several *.csv files that simply contain 2D coordinates (x and y). I read the files line by line and from each pair of x and y I create an object "Point2D". Then I add this "Point2D" to a list that is stored in another object "PointCloud".

Now comes the odd part:
The function "getPointCloudFromCam2Meas" works fine if I only open one single *.csv file. If I open up two files one after another, the second call of the function returns the first point cloud + the second point cloud (appended), even though the local variable "ptc" is initialized as a new "PointCloud" each call.

Why does the program behave like that?

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import numpy as np
import os

class Point2D:
    '''A Point in 2-dimensional space.

    Attributes:
        idx:    The index of the Point.
        x:      The x-coordinate of the Point.
        y:      The y-coordinate of the Point.
    '''
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.idx = Point2D.count
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        Point2D.count += 1

    def displayCoords(self):
        print("My coordinates are {}, {}".format(self.x, self.y))

    def displayIndex(self):
        print("My index is {}".format(self.idx))

class PointCloud:
    '''A Point Cloud defined by x-y-coordinate tuples.

    Attributes:
        name:   The name of the point cloud.
        size:   The number of points within the point cloud.
        center: The center of gravity of the point cloud as a Point2D.
        points: An unsorted list of the Point2D objects that form the PointCloud object
    '''
    count = 0
    points = list()

    def __init__(self):
        PointCloud.count += 1

    def addPoint(self, Point2D):
        self.points.append(Point2D)

    def displayPointCoords(self):
        for point in self.points:
            point.displayCoords()

    def displayPointIdx(self):
        for point in self.points:
            point.displayIndex()

    def displayPointCount(self):
        print("I contain {} points.".format(len(self.points)))

    def getXCoords(self):
        xCoords = list()
        for point in self.points:
            xCoords.append(point.x)
        return xCoords

    def getYCoords(self):
        yCoords = list()
        for point in self.points:
            yCoords.append(point.y)
        return yCoords

    def getCenter(self):
        xCalc = np.sum(self.getXCoords())/len(self.points)
        yCalc = np.sum(self.getYCoords())/len(self.points)
        center = Point2D(xCalc,yCalc)
        return center

def getPointCloudFromCam2Meas(File):
    '''Returns a point cloud object that is read from the *.csv file "File"

    The *.csv files have to be exported from the Cam2Measure Software.'''

    f = open(File)
    k = 0
    ptc = PointCloud()
    line = f.readline()
    while len(line) != 0:
        linefrag = line.split(";")
        # first line is the headerline, so skip it
        if k > 0:
            x = float(linefrag[3])
            y = float(linefrag[4])
            pt = Point2D(x, y)
            ptc.addPoint(pt)
        line = f.readline()
        k += 1
    f.close()
    return ptc

# Main Program
File2 = "Testfile2.csv"
print("Creating point cloud from file \"{}\"".format(File2))
lvPointCloud2 = getPointCloudFromCam2Meas(File2)
lvPointCloud2.getCenter().displayCoords()
lvPointCloud2.displayPointCount()

File3 = "Testfile3.csv""
print("Creating point cloud from file \"{}\"".format(File3))
lvPointCloud3 = getPointCloudFromCam2Meas(File3)
lvPointCloud3.getCenter().displayCoords()
lvPointCloud3.displayPointCount()
```

**Testfile2.csv**

Aktiviert;Merkmal;ID;x;y;z;i;j;k;Abweichung von bester Passform;Geräteposition;Messsonde;Gerätename
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen01;1;697.652;-1009.629;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen01;2;696.667;-1010.01;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen01;3;695.621;-1010.367;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen01;4;694.589;-1010.682;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen01;5;693.561;-1010.955;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen01;6;692.568;-1011.183;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen01;7;691.479;-1011.394;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen01;8;690.377;-1011.561;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen01;9;689.283;-1011.687;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552

**Testfile3.csv**

Aktiviert;Merkmal;ID;x;y;z;i;j;k;Abweichung von bester Passform;Geräteposition;Messsonde;Gerätename
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;1;379.598;-866.472;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;2;378.762;-867.039;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;3;377.882;-867.628;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;4;377.05;-868.199;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;5;376.123;-868.819;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;6;375.293;-869.388;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;7;374.461;-869.952;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;8;373.561;-870.56;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;9;372.723;-871.125;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;10;371.797;-871.756;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;11;370.811;-872.418;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;12;369.929;-873.015;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552
Ausgewählt;FATre ID31396 Innen02;13;368.989;-873.64;0;;;;;Geräteposition 1;3;P08-02-05-21552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `class PointCloud:`

You declare points as a **class variable**:

```
points = list()
```

and then every instance of **PointCloud** shares that `points`

Sometimes this is desired behavior, but it's generally not the OO way to share data among instances.

[This Python2 tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/object_oriented_programming.php) has a decent introduction to class vs. instance variables.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Based upon your reply I removed that "points = list()" line and put the following line into the init(): self.points = list(). Now the program does what I wanted it to do.